# Issue with images in spreadsheet and App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue with apps script when I insert the image in spreadsheet and then convert it to pdf. The image doesn't appear in the document pdf.

My code is:

here insert the image

```
libro=SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
hojaX=Libro.getSheetByName('Test');
hojax.insertImage("http://test.com/imagen.jpg", 3, 71, 0, 0);
```

here  convert the spreadsheet in pdf

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
```

here attach to email to send

```
var attach = {fileName:'name.pdf',content:file, mimeType:'application/pdf'};  

MailApp.sendEmail(test@test.com, "title", "message" {attachments:[attach]});
```

I can't fix, the pdf send without image, could you help me?
regards

Comment: The script isn't complete. Please checkout [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to [insert an image in App Script](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/examples/spreadsheetapp#insert-image-in-a-spreadsheet).

```
function myFunction() {
  var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcdefghiklmnopqrstopwxyz/edit#gid=0';
   var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      'http://i.imgur.com/PnJTXjN.png'); //url of the image
  var binaryData = response.getContent();

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');
  sheet.insertImage(blob, 1, 1); //this puts the image in A1 of the cell 
}
```

Here's how to convert Image to PDF and attach in your email courtesy of [Amit Agarwal](https://ctrlq.org/code/20043-convert-image-to-pdf). When you run this code, a message will be sent to your mail with the pdf attached.

```
function convertImageToPDF() {

 var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://i.imgur.com/DS6bVac.png');

  // grab its bytes and base64-encode them.
  var base64 = Utilities.base64Encode(image.getBlob().getBytes());
  var html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+base64+'" />';

  // create a blob, convert to PDF
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, MimeType.HTML).setName('myImage' + ".pdf");

  //save to Google Drive
   var file = {
    title: 'myImage.pdf',
    mimeType: 'application/pdf'
  };
   file = Drive.Files.insert(file,blob.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);

  //send to email as attached file
  MailApp.sendEmail("youremail@gmail.com", "Image to PDF", "", {
    attachments:blob.getAs(MimeType.PDF)
  });

}
```

Comment: dont work, I try this code, but the pdf file dont have image.